# SSL to Wordpress with Traefik

Tags: wordpress, ssl, traefik, rancher

I am running on Rancher platform and I have set up wordpress through wordpress stack. It is currently running on port 80 http. I wish to insert a free SSL with Let's encrypt and I know that Traefik stack is able to generate one for my wordpress. But I don't exactly know how.

Things that I tried:

1. I create a volume on wordpress `/mnt/docker/traefik/acme:/etc/letsencrypt/acme`
2. I configure Traefik with HTTP challenges, insert a proper email for acme and so on.
3. Not working =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rancher can manage your SSL certificates.

Here are the steps:

- Add certificate (https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.6/en/environments/certificates/)
- Create a load balancer service, with the hostname needed for your wordpress certificate, select the appropriate ports, select the certificate.
- Now the wordpress website would be available on the port selected in the Loadbalancer rules.